# Changing the background of a column cell value of an based on the Value (HTML Reported created by awk)

Tags: awk, html

I have created an HTML Table (Data from the DB) using awk. I am stuck at creating the Background of a column, depending on the cell value. Not much idea about css. I am abble to change the ont bbased on the condition but not the background color. here is my code. If the status is less than 100 background should be red..else same bg as rest of the table..

```
BEGIN {
  print "<html><body></br></br>The report provides overall Percentage Secured in the given subjects.</br></br></br>"
  print "<table border=1 bgcolor= \'LemonChiffon\" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1>"
}

NR==1 {
  # Header row
  print "<tr>"

  for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
    print "<td><b>"$i"</b></td>"
  }
  print "</tr>"
}

NR>1 {
  # Data rows
  print "<tr>"
  if( $i < 100 ) {
    color="RED"  \\ Background should be Red if the status is less tha 100\\
}
  if( $i == 100 ) {
    color="BLACK" \\Same background as rest o the table\\
  }
  print "<td><b><FONT COLOR=\""color"\" FACE=\"verdana\" SIZE=2>"$1"</b></FONT></td><td>"$2"</td><td>"$3"</td><td>"$4"</td><td>"$5"</td>"
  print "</tr>"
}
END {
  print "</table></body></html>"
}
```

Comment: In addition to this being essentially a duplicate of your other question, to which the answer is the same, you are really asking about how to write HTML here, which is beyond the scope of U&L.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old but good reference for basic css properties: http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/css/properties.html

I would do

```
BEGIN {
  print "<html><head>"
  print "<title> Set the page title here </title>"
  print "<style type=\"text/css\">"
  print ".error {
  print "   color: red,"
  print "   font-size: larger,"
  print "   // other properties... take care, no trailing comma allowed"
  print "}"
  print "</style></head>"
  print "<body>"
  # use P tags, not BR line breaks -- easier to apply styling.
  print "<p>The report provides overall Percentage Secured in the given subjects.</p>"
  print "<table border=1 bgcolor=\"LemonChiffon\" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1>"
}

NR == 1 {...} # I would use TH tags for the headers

NR > 1 {
  # Data rows
  print "<tr>"
  for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
    class = $i < 100 ? "class=\"error\"" : ""
    printf "<td %s>%s</td>\n", class, $i
  }
  print "</tr>"
}
```

Putting styles in one place will help if

Comment: I have used the above code, but the background color hasn't changed ..Its remaining the same...

Comment: Perhaps you should do a little research to find the correct css property for background colour. Hint, there's a link right there.

Comment: Oh I am doing that, since morning. My limited knowledge of CSS is making things difficult,...I have (Still trying as i am typing) tried different combinations but in vain....Hope to fix this soon...

Comment: Thank you so much DopeGhoti && Glenn Jackman. With little changes to the abbove script i am able to acheive the intended result. Thank you once again guys..Changes required were inserting "backgroud-color=red; (Notice, i have replaced comma with semi colon)...

Comment: Can I add add an if-else condition to above HTML Code. I did try using one, but its throwing an error...

Comment: I tried adding an if else statement by adding one additional class ".monitor" but, the script is throwing an error.